# Displaying a multiple-plot graph using r_fun_plot

Tags: opencpu

I am having trouble displaying a multiple-plot graph using the ocpu javascript function `r_fun_plot()`. The R function that is called creates two or more plots use the `par()` function to lay them out in a matrix. If I call my R function locally (from within RStudio) I will get the correct result. However, when called remotely using `r_fun_plot()` and with a target of an empty DIV element, no plots are displayed - only the "pdf svg png" pointers are displayed. Clicking these pointers gives a page with the following text:

```
attempt to select less than one element

In call:
myplots[[index]]
```

`myplots` is not in my javascript code or in opencpu.js Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post an example of your R function so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Ah. It's at work. I'll post it first thing Monday. Thanks.

Comment: It would have been too difficult to recreate my code because of its dependencies. So, I created a little test project and, I'm happy to say, multiple plots worked just fine. So, I've got to dig deeper in my code to see what the problem is.